# Java: How to create an object with and without parameters?

Tags: java

How do I create an object with Parameters such as :

A:

```
double[ ] coe = f2, 4, 5, 1g;
Polynomial h = new Polynomial(coe);
```

and at the same time allow the object to be created without any explicit parameters such as :

B:

```
Polynomial f = new Polynomial( );
```

Do I need two seperate classes because when I create my constructor for the class then if I pick either A or B then the other one will be undefined ?

Comment: 1) Make sure to post valid code 2) Both will "work" *if* the appropriate constructors are available. Java classes can have multiple constructors. In the latter case you'll also need to provide a way to 'update' the created object for it to be useful. (I'm a fan of immutable objects, when allowable.)

Comment: @sstan solved my issue thanks!